# When is an iOS app terminated in the simulator? (Xcode 9, Beta 5)

Tags: xcode, events, simulator

Short: Does Xcode 9 b5's simulator incorrectly report system events or events from quit and re-launched apps back to the Xcode console?

Longer:
Using Xcode 9 beta 5 
(simulator version listed as: Version 10.0 (SimulatorApp-829.3 )
If I make just one change to the standard single-view application viewController.swift file, adding a 
print("*** viewDidLoad() has executed at (Date())")
inside of viewDidLoad, then build & run.
App runs in the simulator.
I see the expected print result in the Xcode console

while app still runs in the simulator, I return home (shift-cmd-H) and then to the first icon home screen (another shift-cmd-H)
I double tap home button (twice rapidly shift-cmd-H) to get the app switcher.
I swipe up on my running still-running app.
I get a "Terminated due to signal 9" debugger message under the line that printed above, as expected.

If, in the still-running simulator, I double-click the icon for the app I just quit, the app loads, as expected, BUT…
-   The console doesn't clear
-   There is no new "*** viewDidLoad()…" statement, (I added Date() to the printout to verify it wasn't simply overwriting the prior statement). There's no new statement at all.

Am I experiencing a simulator bug, or do I have it wrong to think that swiping an app up from the iOS App Switcher will terminate the app AND remove it from memory so a subsequent app load will execute viewDidLoad anew?

Thanks!
John

Answer (score 0):

It might have to do with Xcode debugger tethering to the app.  Try your proof again, only without using Xcode debugging.  Just launch the app from within simulator and watch the device console (via Xcode's Devices window) after you kill and relaunch the app.